# customising ISBN, location, venue, volume, edition, series, dates, etc. fields of books, proceedings, etc. in biblatex APA style

Tags: biblatex, macros, bibliographies, apa-style

I have the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatextest.bib}
@article{W00,
  author = "Wayne, J.",
  title = "Article with volume number and doi",
  journal = "Journal A",
  volume = "X",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "1-2",
  year = "2000",
  doi  = "10.1007/...",
  url  = ""
}
@article{L00,
  author = "Lee, B.",
  title = "Article without volume number, but with url",
  journal = "Journal B",
  volume = "",
  number = "Y",
  pages = "3-4",
  year = "2000",
  doi  = "",
  url  = "https://..."
}
@book{J92,
  author = "Jordan, M.",
  title = "{Fundamentals of Basketball}",
  edition = "1",
  publisher = "Chicago University Press",
  location  = "Chicago",
  isbn = "87654321",
  doi = "",
  url = "",
  year = "1992"
}
@inproceedings{D21,
  author = "Delon, A.",
  title = "{Article title}",
  editor = "Edith, I.",
  booktitle = "{Proceedings of Symposium A}",
  series = "Series of Symposia Proceedings",
  volume = "1",
  edition = "2",
  pages = "5-6",
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
  location = "London",
  isbn = "12345678",
  doi = "",
  url = "",
  year = "2021",
  eventtitle = "Symposium A",
  venue = "Oxford",
  eventdate = "2020-09-01/2020-09-05"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-apa}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue,colorlinks=true,linktocpage,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered}

\usepackage{xpatch}
  \xpretobibmacro{doi+url}{\printfield{isbn}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}
    {\clearfield{labelmonth}% don't want months in citations
     \clearfield{labelday}% don't want days in citations
     \clearfield{labelendmonth}% don't want months in citations
     \clearfield{labelendday}% don't want days in citations
     \iffieldsequal{labelyear}{labelendyear}% Don't want no-op year ranges
       {\clearfield{labelendyear}}
       {}%
     \iffieldundef{origyear}
       {}
       {\printorigdate%
        \setunit*{\addslash}}%
     \iffieldundef{related}
       {}
       {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprintfrom}
         {\entrydata*{\thefield{related}}{\printlabeldateextra}%
          \setunit*{\addslash}}
         {}}%
     \printlabeldateextra}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
    {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:author}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}%
   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
        {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
          {\printnames{labelname}}%
          {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {\printnames{shortauthor}}
             {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
               {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
               {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}%
              \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
           \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}%
   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
         \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {\printnames{labelname}}%
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
             {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
             {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}%
            \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Compact cite - more than one thing for same author
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
% New cite
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \setunit{\textcitedelim}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
     % No author/editor
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    % Cite using title
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:noname}}%
      \setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}%
          \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}}
    % Cite using shorthand
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
  % Normal cite with author/editor
  % Normal full cite
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
    % Normal full cite
       {\printnames{labelname}}
    % Cite using short author
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {\printnames{shortauthor}}
             {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
               {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
               {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}}}}%
  % Year
        \setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}%
  % Put the shortauthor inside the year brackets if necessary
        \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
          \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
           {}
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {}
             {\printnames{shortauthor}%
              \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
  % Print prenote (belongs to first cite)
          \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
  % Actual year printing
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
  % Save name hash for checks later
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\citep{W00}

\citet{L00}

\citep{J92}

\citet{D21}

\printbibliography

\fussy
\end{document}
```

As you see, not all fields from the book and proceedings references are standardly written on the .pdf output file when using APA style. How can I have all these fields written? Note that I already could write the ISBN field (which is not standardly printed in APA style) with the two code lines after the hyperref package setup (though the ISBN font is different, so it could be that this is a rather quick fix). The large piece of code after that until the start of the document has to do with hyperlinking author + year, which was addressed in a separate question. Also note the wicked year output for the proceedings. Probaly, one should use a date field, instead of an year field, across the whole .bib file when using biblatex. I will try to add a book collection type of entry in the coming hours. With that, one should hopefully address costumisation of most if not all relevant type of bibliographic entries in APA style. I am aware that one might instead of customising APA style, customise some other style like authoryear or its variants, but please bear in mind that the target is to have essentially APA style, but with all fields from books, proceedings, book collections, and so forth an so on, printed or at least have the option to do so. A secondary target could be also to drop the comma before & (or to keep the comma and drop all &s as seen in some "Harvard styles") for two-author references; but that has less priority.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Although you mention this, I think you're still going to have an easier time starting out with a standard author-year style than customizing the `apa` style, since the `apa` style implements the peculiarities required specifically by the APA.  But it's also not entirely clear what your question is, in fact.

Comment: **@Alan**: the question is clear. I would like to have all fields of the book and inproceedings entries in the filecontents section, visible, i.e. printed in the .pdf's list of references, while keeping the remaining features of the APA style..............

Comment: **@Alan**: nothing against customising the `authoryear` style, but as I said, I essentially want most of the features of the APA style, with only some "minor" modifications, namely printed ISBN, volume, edition, publisher, publisher's location, venue, etc., where appropriate; so I think it should be easier to make those modifications on the APA style.............. if someone can give me information on which bibmacros of the APA style contain these fields, and some basic examples on how to redefine the bibmacros, I can try to do that myself..............